# DataGridColumns in ResourceDictionaries

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

This is a kind of a design-question and not a problem.

In the view of my application I have a `DataGrid` with a lot of columns. The lines of code of the columndefinitions is above 1000. This comes through very big `DataGridTemplateColumn`-Definitions with different cellstyles and `CellEditingTemplate`s and so on.

Through the fact that there are several persons working on this view at the same time and we often have to merge I was wondering if there is a way to make this simpler.

My idea now is to move some(or all) columns to a `ResourceDictionary`.

But if I move all columndefinitions to the same `ResourceDictionary` I still have the problem that we often have to merge if we want to check in to the TFS.

Now I thought about moving each `DataGridTemplateColumn` to a separate `ResourceDictionary` but I'm not sure if this is a good way to solve this problem. What do you think? Any advices?

Some `DataGridTemplateColumn`-Definitions are over 100 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have columns as resources like this --

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Key="SharedColumn1" x:Shared="False" Header="1" Width="Auto">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock  Text="Hello"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And then use it in your datagrid like this ...

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="SharedColumn1"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="YourCustomColumn"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Also, keep in mind that columns is actually a collection with data grid, so if there are like a lot of columns that you have to reuse, you can infact create a base grid with all the common columns, and then use that base grid in your control, and in you control you can add specific columns as you might need.

Comment: Yes, I know. I want to know if it is a good way to move each columndefinition into a separate ResourceDictionary

Comment: why a separate dictionary for each column ?

Comment: Because the definition of one column is above 100 lines